# Android repeat song

Tags: android, task, repeat

I want to repeat the song perodic by 1minutes.
when the song finish playing wait 1 minute and restart
Please help

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
              mPlayer.start();
              mPlayer.setLooping(true);
             } 
           });
        }};
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 60000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 1 minutes? Do you want to start the song every 1 minute? you want to wait 1 minute after it is finished and start again?

Comment: yes my friends. exactly. when the song finish, wait 1minute and restart

Comment: @Merv what is the need for a  timer? You can just do `mPlayer.setLooping(true);` stop the player when you want to

Comment: the problem is that my application sends a notification (SMS) to the client until it reads the SMS.
So without reading SMS I always ringing my song every minute

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the completion event in order to know when the song finishes.
Once the event is fired, than, start your delayed execution (no need for timer).

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
     { 

          mHandler .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   mPlayer.start();      
               }
          }, 60000);

     }
});
```